# Questions on using enums as parameters and if/else conditions

Tags: c#

Is it possible to do the following with an enum in C#?:

- Pass in to a method a selected value of the enum (eg if an enum has members such as Red, Green, Orange, I can pass in Colors.Red).
- In the method body of the above method which accepts an enum, I can say if (Enum == Colors.Red).

What would be the syntax for this? I've always seemed to have stalled on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just like you would with any other type ...

```
public void MyMethod( Color color )
{
   if( color == Color.Red )
      ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for you because your enum is the only one that follows naming standards: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x252001(v=VS90).aspx

Comment: Indeed, I always cringe when I see someone giving a plural name to an enum, when the enum has no 'Flags' attribute.

Comment: Good point (Fred). So simple, and yet I had it correct! Bit of a slow moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
public enum Colors{
   Red,
   Blue
}

...

public void DoSomething(Colors theColor){
   if(theColor == Colors.Red) // do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. This is a simple example:

```
public enum Colors
{
    Red,
    Orange,
    Green
}

...

public bool IsRed(Colors c)
{
    if (c == Colors.Red)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Your function call would look like:

```
bool test = IsRed(Colors.Green); //false
```

Comment: Why do I hate that style of writing methods so much?

Comment: I feel you, it just gets under your skin.  `return c == Colors.Red` is about as clean and friendly as you can get.

Comment: I generally don't write methods like that, just trying to make things more obvious for the OP.

Comment: Why even have an IsRed method?

Comment: Because he asked for a method that accepts an enum as a parameter, yeesh. So much hate :x

Answer (score -1):

Yes and yes. Syntax is just as you have there.

Comment: `Enum == Color.Red` as he has it is not correct for what he's asking.  You can't compare the Enum class to an enum value.

Comment: Actually, i'm very sure that the "Enum" he put in that context is the parameter... something like: void Method(Color Enum). That's what I gather from his question. What reason is there to vote my answer down? I believe this is a fully legitimate answer..

Comment: The fact that it is a class doesn't matter, as I'm sure the OP is smart enough to know to avoid that.

Comment: In all fairness, your answer is more of a comment because it doesn't answer his question of how to set up the method signature.  You've made assumptions about code that wasn't posted.